# iOS: Webview does not execute javascript for the second NSURLRequest for the same url

Tags: c#, jquery, ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I am new to iOS development using MonoTouch
I am opening a url inside a webview which displays details of user  after login into the app, the details of user is displayed for the first time but when the user log out and login again the page renders as it is but the user details are not displayed.

JavaScript is not working on second load, that is what i feel.

What may be possible reason and solution, please suggest.

Here is What i am doing :

on **ViewDidLayoutSubviews**:

```
NSUrlRequest url= (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl ("http://www.xyz.com/Home/OAuth/?userId="+GlobalData.UserId+"&userName="+GlobalData.UserName)));

NSUrlCache.SharedCache.RemoveCachedResponse(url);

this.MainWebView.LoadRequest (url);
```

Comment: *sidenote:* it's **iOS** , not **IOS** . and where is your code ?

Comment: thanx a lot shivan Raptor, in first line of query i have written i am new to iOS development. Made the changes suggested by you.

Comment: **JavaScript is not working on second load, that is what i feel** Could we have something stronger than feelings ? like a complete test case showcasing the **fact** that it's not working ?

Comment: No error at all? what if the URL is loaded in desktop browser? Any JS error?

Comment: there is no error in desktop browser and even it is working fine in iPad and iPhone browsers, but coming to app, JS doesn't fires on second time calling same url. @Shivan

Comment: @Stephane Delcroix, I am not getting the proper reason for error that is why i can say what i feel.

Comment: but where is your JavaScript codes ? impossible to debug for you without codes.

Comment: thanx @ShivanRaptor , problem solved by me, it was just a stupid mistake done by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, problem was not with the JS, I was just missing a simple stuff of clearing webview when it is closed.
I just added

```
this.TableWebView.LoadHtmlString("",null);
```

For Clearing WebView on log off and it works fine for me, Thanx shivan for your attention.